/boot to small to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. Purged everything
/boot reports 768 MB, 35.6 is free, disks are encrypted using LUKS. The disk /boot is using a has 1.8tb free, but the partition reports /boot (/dev/sd2) is 768 mb. The encrypted data partition labeled as /dev/sda3 has 1.8tb free. Data on the other disks, there are 7 total, needs to be kept intact. It's impossible for me to backup 4.5 TB of data. So far all solutions have not allowed an upgrade. Deleted all old kernel data, changed compression in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf. It didn't help.  After deleting everything old in /boot and changing compression in initramfs the upgrade reports 166mb needs to be freed. I can upgrade using ISO and USB, but don't want to lose the encrypted data on the other 6 disks. Moving /boot seems like the best option, but since the disks are encrypted this increases the difficulty. Suggestions are welcome.
